How to break bookdown caption in several pages?
I'm writing my thesis using bookdown and I'm facing right now a little problem, I have a figure that fits almost the entire space of the page (B5 format) so when I add the caption to the figure, the caption starts in the same page and it disappears (right picture), it doesn't continue in the next page, and it even exceeds the margin limits. In fact, if I open the rendered PDF with a graphical vector editing software (Inkscape) the full caption is there but outside the page limits (left picture).

I've been reading a bit about how LaTex deals with figures and I guess the problem is that the figure by default is a floating element and LaTex try to place together the figure and the caption, so my question is:
How can I make the figure not to be a floating element so the caption can be placed on the following page?
